# PHP Order by facebook likes

Tags: php, facebook

I've been working with PHP for a while, but I'm not an expert in any way. I've got a website (WIP) where i upload all my photos that I've taken. However, every photo has a facebook like button, so my visitors can like my photos or share them with friends.

I've seen lots of people sorting articles/photos etc by facebook likes? I've been searching around but there seems to be a lot of questions and less answers. I've just found a few Wordpress plugins (and I'm not working with WP, so that's not needed).

Dose any one here know how i can do this? maybe got a tutorial/snippet i can have a look at? I imagine i need to store the likes in my own database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run a FQL query like this:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, total_count
FROM link_stat WHERE url in ("facebook.com", "google.com")
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```

You would want to send all of your url's in, and you would want to cache this result.  You can test this query [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) and you can learn how to execute this FQL query [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

Comment: Selecting `total_count` will give the count that's shown on the Like button itself (sum of share_count, like_count, and comment_count), which might (or might not) yield better-sorted results, depending on the case.